# Creating a deployment package for solution with multiple projects in VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, package

I have a solution containing 14 projects.  I am trying to create a deployment package for this solution. I can use the wizard to package a single project to be deployed on our remote server; however, I'm having a hard time finding any information about packaging a solution with multiple projects.

First, is it possible to create a deployment package for the solution rather than a project;

Second, would anyone be able to point to any information on this subject (packaging a solution with multiple projects - not how to create a deployment package for a project).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to create a deployment package for the solution rather than a project?

Don't know your purpose of creating a package for solution, but to simply answer your question - No, you can't package the whole solution. The package option in VS 2010 and 2012 is to create one deployable project which includes artefacts like website, SQL for another environment like Test Or Production.

However, you can **zip** up the solution in VS2012, which is a new feature by right clicking the solution to create a minified version of solution for portability.

Best source of information is [microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/02/09/web-packaging-creating-a-web-package-using-vs-2010.aspx).

Comment: I agree, in Visual Studio a solution is nothing more than a construct that allows projects to be grouped together for the purposes of code organization. The unit of deployment is the project.

Comment: @Kevin: I disagree. The unit of deployment is in between solution and projects. What you say holds true only for limited solutions, where one project describes the total deliverables.

Comment: Also multiple packages for multiple projects can be created from within one solution.

Comment: @Nexus - thanks, I think this is what I should have been trying to do. "Also multiple packages for multiple projects can be created from within one solution."

Answer (score 0):

Deployment is much more than what visual studio offers as deployment.

For a high learning curve and all options, see:

Wix 3.6 
wix.codeplex.com

We use this tool for the problem you describe.